# Why we have to proof both $Q$ and $R$ in $P\implies (Q\lor R)$

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

I'm studying proofs trying to use logic before starting with the proof.

A direct proof can be written as $P\implies Q$, by forcing $P$ to be true, we have to force $Q$ to be true so the statement stays true.

But in a case of the form $P\implies (Q \lor R)$, why do we have to prove both propositions to be true ($Q, R$) individually? True tables states 3 cases to be true when $P$ is true in this particular case

| P | Q | R | $P\implies (Q\lor R)$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | T | T |
| T | T | F | T |
| T | F | T | T |

Suppose $x\in\mathbb{R}$. If $xy$ is even, then $x$ is even or $y$ in even.

In this case it also applies my reasoning through true tables. We just need to show that $x$ is even to proof $xy$ is also even. No matter which value $y$ have, it'll always be true $xy$ are even in $x$ is even.

What's the logic behind my wrong reasoning and why it is a must to proof both by cases, $x$ being even and $y$ being even?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If $P\implies Q$ is true, then $P\implies (Q\lor R)$ is also true. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: You just need to show that "$x$ is even" ($Q$) to prove "$x$ is even or $y$ is even" ($Q \lor R$). But given "$xy$ is even", $Q$ is not always true.

Comment: You don't have to prove both $Q\land R$. But you have to prove $Q\lor R$.

Comment: @5xum I'm asking why in direct proofs we have to proof both propositions $Q$ be true and $R$ be true? Why not just proof $Q$, which lead us to affirm $P\implies (Q\lor R)$ is true?

Comment: "We just need to show that x is even to proof xy is also even."  But what if $x$ is odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, proving that $P\implies Q$ is **sufficient** to prove that $P\implies Q\lor R$. Sufficient, **but not necessary**, and in fact, often times, proving $P\implies Q$ may be **impossible**!

Take, for example, the statement "If I have fewer than $2$ legs, then I either have one leg or I have no legs". Clearly, this is a true statement in which $P$ is "I have fewer than $2$ legs", $Q$ is "I have one leg" and $R$ is "I have no legs". So, in this case,

1. the statement $P\implies Q\lor R$ is true,
2. The statement $P\implies Q$ is false (since it equals "If I have fewer than two legs, I must have one leg", a statement contradicted by the existence of people with no legs)
3. The statement $P\implies R$ is false (since it equals "If I have fewer than two legs, I must have no legs", a statement contradicted by the existence of people with one leg)

---

In your case, if $P$ is "$xy$ is even", $Q$ is "$x$ is even" and $R$ is "$y$ is even", then proving $P\implies Q$ will be impossible, because the statement is false.

However, it is also not true, as you say, that you need to prove **both** propositions, i.e. both $Q$ and $R$. You only need to prove that $Q\lor R$ is true, i.e. that *one of them* is true. You don't have to prove that a specific single one of them is true, as that can be, as it is in your case, impossible.

What you can do, and what I advise you to do in this case, is to prove is that if $P$ is true, and $Q$ is false, then $R$ **must** be true.